# How to use ng-options to set the same text no matter the option selected - Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I understand how to set the default value of the options box.

My question is different in that there is a default value "Actions" - and there are 3 other filtering options that can be selected...

```css
    $scope.actions = [
  {display_name:"Actions", type:"unknown", box_display: "Actions"},
  {display_name:"Mark all incoming voicemails as read", type:"read", box_display: "Actions"},
  {display_name:"Mark all incoming voicemails as unread", type:"unread", box_display: "Actions"},
  {display_name:"Delete all read incoming voicemails", type:"delete", box_display: "Actions"},
    ];
$scope.selectedAction = $scope.actions[0];
```

```html
<select class="XButton XButtonNormal XButtonDropDown disabled-false" ng-model="selectedAction"
            ng-options = "action_option.display_name for action_option in actions"
            ng-change="handleVoiceMailAction(selectedAction.type)"
        >
            <option>Actions</option>
```

How do I get the selection box to display "Actions" no matter which of the 4 objects in the array is selected. The different options still need to be visible when selecting the options (and the functionality needs to correspond to the appropriate selection), but I want the box to continue to  display "Actions" after a selection is made.

Comment: Can you clarify what labels do you want to see when you open the dropdown? "Actions" for all the actions, i.e. four times or "Actions", "Mark all incoming voicemails as read", ... ?

Comment: The latter Michael P. The dropdown should display the different display_names, but I need the selection box to return to saying "Actions" after the selection has been made (and the dropdown is no longer open)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you look for :

***Template :***

```
<select ng-model="selectedAction" ng-options="action.display_name for action in actions" 
                                  ng-change="setCurrentAction(selectedAction)"></select>
<p>Current action : {{currentAction}}</p>
```

***Controller :***

```
$scope.actions = [{
    display_name: "Actions",
    type: "unknown"
}, {
    display_name: "Mark all incoming voicemails as read",
    type: "read"
}, {
    display_name: "Mark all incoming voicemails as unread",
    type: "unread"
}, {
    display_name: "Delete all read incoming voicemails",
    type: "delete"
}];

$scope.selectedAction = $scope.currentAction = $scope.actions[0];

$scope.setCurrentAction = function (action) {
    $scope.currentAction = action;
    $scope.selectedAction = $scope.actions[0];
};
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/mqfqweLo/6/)**

**Explanation:**

As you want to display 'Action' for the action binded to the `ng-model` attribute of the dropdown, we have to make the distinction between the `selectedAction` *from the dropdown point of view*, and the selected action for your application logic. I called that latter action the `currentAction`. On a selection event, we have to *register* the selected action to the current action.